# My code is not picking up the latest file in the folder

Tags: excel, vba

Problem is simple. Not getting the latest file. And this problem only creeped up because of new year. It was working fine last year

Here is the relevant code:

```
 Dim yr As String
 Dim mo As String
 Dim destinationsfn As String
 Dim destinationtsfn
 Dim bdate As String
 Dim fdate As String
 Dim destinationfp As String
 Dim destinationfo As String
 Dim destinationShVar As Worksheet
 Dim destinationTorc As Workbook

 Dim sht As Worksheet

 yr = Format(Date, "yyyy")
 mo = Format(Date, "mm")  

 If mo < 10 Then
 mo = Right(mo, 1)
 End If


 destinationfo = Dir("W:\Product Platforms\Macro\New destination Database\destination Master File\" & yr & "\" & mo & "*", vbDirectory)
 destinationfo = Trim(destinationfo)

 destinationfp = "W:\Product Platforms\Macro\New destination Database\destination Master File\" & yr & "\" & destinationfo & "\"

 destinationsfn = Dir(destinationfp & "*-*.xlsx")

Do While Len(destinationsfn) > 0
fdate = FileDateTime(destinationfp & destinationsfn)
    If fdate > bdate Then
        destinationtsfn = destinationsfn
        bdate = fdate
    End If
    destinationsfn = Dir
Loop   

 On Error Resume Next
 Workbooks.Open (destinationfp & destinationtsfn)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Is it finding the correct source folder?

Comment: Yeah, did the debugging and its only picking up the file of Jan 2nd and not Jan 4th

Comment: so its pikcking up 1-2.xlsx and not 1-4 xlsx

Comment: Are the results from FileDateTime as you expect?  Try adding `Debug.print destinationsfn, fdate` inside the dir loop and check the output

Comment: `fdate` and `bdate` are both strings on this line `If fdate > bdate Then` (as that's what they're declared as). Shouldn't you convert them to dates prior to/during the comparison on the line? Does that make a difference? Conversion can be done with `cdate()`.

Comment: If you are in the US, a string `"12/31/2018"` will evaluate as being greater than a string `"01/01/2019"` I think -- due to alphabetical order (as the variables aren't dates).

Comment: Not sure why my debug print isn't working and i am in Canada, would that make a difference?

Comment: @Piccinin, if Excel shows you dates in `MM/DD/YYYY` format (due to your regional/local settings), then yes, it might do (as `FileDateTime` will return a Variant Date, which gets converted to a string according to these settings). Either way, I would consider declaring `bdate` and `fdate` as variants or dates, so that the `>` operator is comparing dates and not strings -- and so that your code is not sensitive to the user's locale settings.

Comment: Hey Chillin it worked, can you post this as answer so i mark it as correct answer?

Comment: @Piccinin, sure, have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fdate` and `bdate` are both declared as strings.

So, on this line:

`If fdate > bdate Then`

You aren't comparing dates with the `>` operator. You're comparing strings, which means alphabetical order is considered.

If you are in the US or any country that formats dates as `"MM/DD/YYY..."` and your locale settings in Excel reflect this, then the string `"12/31/2018"` will evaluate as being greater than a string `"01/01/2019"`, due to alphabetical order. If they were dates, the opposite would be true.

Easiest fix might be just to declare both `bdate` and `fdate` as variant or date.